# Plotting DiscretePlot3D with Negative Exponents

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale

I want to use DiscretePlot3D on a Table of values that have Negative Exponents. However, its results ends up giving a taller plot to the values with lower values (i.e. 10^-21 has a taller plot than 10^-9).

```
ALPHAkSUBTRACTED = {{2.889`*^-19, 3.856`*^-17, 3.952`*^-15, 
        3.962`*^-13, 3.963`*^-11, 3.963`*^-9}, {2.889`*^-21, 3.856`*^-19, 
        3.952`*^-17, 3.962`*^-15, 3.963`*^-13, 3.963`*^-11}, {2.889`*^-23,
         3.856`*^-21, 3.952`*^-19, 3.962`*^-17, 3.963`*^-15, 
        3.963`*^-13}, {2.889`*^-25, 3.856`*^-23, 3.952`*^-21, 3.962`*^-19,
         3.963`*^-17, 3.963`*^-15}, {2.889`*^-27, 3.856`*^-25, 
        3.952`*^-23, 3.9623`*^-21, 3.963`*^-19, 
        3.963`*^-17}, {2.889`*^-29, 3.856`*^-27, 3.952`*^-25, 3.962`*^-23,
         3.963`*^-21, 3.963`*^-19}};
    
    DiscretePlot3D[
       Callout[ALPHAkSUBTRACTED[[Mass, Radius]], 
         StringForm["M=`` g
        & Rad=``m", SCIENTIFICparticleclass[[Mass]], 
       SCIENTIFICparticleclass[[Radius]] ], Above], {Mass, 1,
          6}, {Radius, 1, 6}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
     ExtentSize -> 0.5, AxesLabel -> {"Mass", "Radius", "alphaK"},
       PlotLabel -> 
      "Photophoretic Deviation between Different Radiuses and Masses of \
    Particles", ImageSize -> 1000, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

Plots the following Matrix

[image: Matrix to Plot]

Into the DiscretePlot3D of:

[image: Discrete Plot 3D]

How do I plot the following DiscretePlot3D in order to make the red pillar the tallest and the purple pillar the shortest. Is there a certain Scaling Function that I can use in order to plot the one with the lowest value to be the shortest (10^-23) and the highest value to be the longest (10^-9)?  Also, What Rotate Function configuration do I use to automatically 'flip' the plot upside down? The table of values is also attached for reference.

[image: Table to Plot]

Comment: Crossposted Here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2472256?p_p_auth=TW5xbbF1

Comment: You are using a Log scale. On such a scale 1 corresponds to zero. 10^-1 to -1 and 10^-10 tp -10. Therefore, the absolute value of the Log gets larger the smaller (closer to zero) the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ScalingFunctions -> {-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}`:

```
DiscretePlot3D[ALPHAkSUBTRACTED[[Mass, Radius]], {Mass, 1, 
  6}, {Radius, 1, 6}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ExtentSize -> 0.5, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Mass", "Radius", "alphaK"}, 
 ImageSize -> 1000, ScalingFunctions -> {-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. How do I add the Callout Labels to be on top of the 3D bar graphs / pillars ?

Comment: @L_R_G_2021, Could not find a clean way to specify positions in `Callout`. I posted an answer  (which uses an alternative approach to add labels) to your new question.